# Xcode 10 Update: Compiler errors based on deprecation

Tags: ios, deprecated, xcode10, ios12

I'm new to iOS. My problem is that I updated to XCode 10 yesterday and I received a lot of compiler errors based on method and class deprecations. Errors, not warnings !!! E.g. UISearchDisplayController, UIActionSheet etc.

Do I miss something ? Doesn't deprecation mean I should not use because it will be removed in the future but I'm able to use in my current build ?

Many thanks,
Sven

Comment: Can you be more accurate? What type of error? Which language?

Comment: Post your sample code to better unsderstand